# Sinusoid and derivative function

Tags: c++, function, math

I have some object whish moves by sinusoid. I have to animate it each time it reaches the top (or the bottom) of the "wave". I want to do this with derivative function: as we know it changes the value (from positive to negative  or contrary) at that points. So the code is:

```
// Start value
int functionValue = +1;

// Function
float y = k1 * sinf(k2 * Deg2Rad(x)) + y_base;

// Derivative function
float tempValue = -cosf(y);

// Check whether value is changed
if (tempValue * functionValue < 0)
{
   animation = true;
}
functionValue = tempValue;
```

if I will output the `tempValue` it shows strange numbers:

```
0.851513
0.997643
0.0242145
0.690432
0.326303
-0.614262
0.892036
0.1348
0.709843
0.968676
0.0454846
0.920602
-0.423125
0.692132
-0.960107
0.0799654
-0.747722
-0.635241
0.148477
-0.98611
0.900912
-0.877801
0.811632
-0.362743
-0.233856
0.35512
-0.994107
0.885184
-0.468005
0.982489
0.675337
0.661048
0.870765
0.0312914
-0.319066
-0.602956
-0.996169
-0.95627
```

And animation is strange too. Not only at the top of wave. What's wrong is there?

Comment: If `f(x) = k1 * sinf(k2 * Deg2Rad(x)) + y_base`, is not `f'(x) = k1 * k2 * cosf(k2 * Deg2Rad(x))` its derivative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have

```
y = a * sin(b * x) + c
```

derivative of that is

```
y' = a * b * cos(b * x)
```

not

```
y' = -cos(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing your math wrong. Derivative of sin(x) is cos(x), not cos(sin(x)).

should be

```
float tempValue = cosf(k2 * Deg2Rad(x));
```